# Adding rows with missing entries

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

I have a table in the below format with multiple Id's, months (1-72) multiple measures (1-40).
Below is the sample table.
The entries for a few months are missing for each measure as seen (Month 5,8 is missing for Measure1, month 8 and 9 is missing for Measure3 and so on).
I want to create a new measure, say measure 4 which is the sum of 2 measures (say measure1+measure3) for each Id, month.
I tried using the lag/lead functions but I could not account it for missing months.

```
+----+-------+--------------+---------------+
| ID | month | measure name | measure value |
+----+-------+--------------+---------------+
|  1 |     1 | Measure1     |            20 |
|  1 |     2 | Measure1     |            80 |
|  1 |     3 | Measure1     |            60 |
|  1 |     4 | Measure1     |            40 |
|  1 |     6 | Measure1     |           100 |
|  1 |     7 | Measure1     |           250 |
|  1 |     9 | Measure1     |            60 |
|  1 |    10 | Measure1     |            70 |
|  1 |     1 | Measure2     |            40 |
|  1 |     2 | Measure2     |            30 |
|  1 |     3 | Measure2     |            25 |
|  1 |     4 | Measure2     |            75 |
|  1 |     5 | Measure2     |           115 |
|  1 |     6 | Measure2     |            80 |
|  1 |     7 | Measure2     |            85 |
|  1 |     9 | Measure2     |            95 |
|  1 |    10 | Measure2     |           200 |
|  1 |     1 | Measure3     |           220 |
|  1 |     2 | Measure3     |            50 |
|  1 |     3 | Measure3     |            60 |
|  1 |     4 | Measure3     |            90 |
|  1 |     5 | Measure3     |            20 |
|  1 |     6 | Measure3     |            70 |
|  1 |     7 | Measure3     |            80 |
|  1 |    10 | Measure3     |           105 |
+----+-------+--------------+---------------+
```

The final output should look something like this (measure4 = measure1+measure3).

```
+----+-------+--------------+---------------+
| ID | month | measure name | measure value |
+----+-------+--------------+---------------+
|  1 |     1 | Measure4     |           240 |
|  1 |     2 | Measure4     |           130 |
|  1 |     3 | Measure4     |           120 |
|  1 |     4 | Measure4     |           130 |
|  1 |     5 | Measure4     |            20 |
|  1 |     6 | Measure4     |           170 |
|  1 |     7 | Measure4     |           330 |
|  1 |     9 | Measure4     |            60 |
|  1 |    10 | Measure4     |           175 |
+----+-------+--------------+---------------+
```

Can you please help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter on the two measures that you are interested in, then use aggregation:

```
select 
    month,
    'Measure4' measure_name,
    sum(measure_value) measure_value
from mytable 
where measure_name in ('Measure1', 'Measure3')
group by month 
order by month
```

This assumes that at least one of the two measures is available for each month (otherwise you would have missing `month`es in the resultset), which is consistent with your sample data.